# Why are there data discrepancies in my Google Analytics Ecommerce report when I compare year-on-year?

Tags: google, google-analytics, ecommerce

I have found some quite large discrepancies in my Conversions --> Ecommerce --> Product Performance report. The data for the same time period is changing when I use the 'compare to' tool.

The example below shows around a £7k revenue for a product between 11th Jan 22 - 11th Jan 23, but when I tell the report to compare that with the previous year, the data for Jan 22/23 changes dramatically to show a £3k revenue?

[image]

[image]

I have played around with the segments, and the data only matches when I look at All Users - for every other segment the data changes for the same time period when comparing date ranges.

Does anyone have ideas about what could be causing this?